# Split vuejs component registration to different file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

Suppose I have an `app.js` file where I register each component and call that on laravel blade file. But all components are not necessary for all user roles.
That's why I want to split my component reg. to different files and call that file e based on role.
my app.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
window.Vue = Vue;

window.axios = require("axios");
window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
require("promise.prototype.finally").shim();

import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from "vform";
window.Form = Form;

Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);

Vue.component("pagination", require("laravel-vue-pagination"));


import VueCtkDateTimePicker from 'vue-ctk-date-time-picker';
import 'vue-ctk-date-time-picker/dist/vue-ctk-date-time-picker.css';
Vue.component('VueCtkDateTimePicker', VueCtkDateTimePicker);

//sweet alert 2

import swal from "sweetalert2";
window.swal = swal;
const toast = swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: "top-end",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 15000
});
window.toast = toast;

//vue lang

import VueInternationalization from "vue-i18n";
import Locale from "./vue-i18n-locales.generated";

Vue.use(VueInternationalization);

const lang = document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2);
// or however you determine your current app locale

const i18n = new VueInternationalization({
    locale: lang,
    messages: Locale
});

//vue lang end

//https://hamed-ehtesham.github.io/pretty-checkbox-vue/#installation

import PrettyCheckbox from "pretty-checkbox-vue";
Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox);

//vue autocomplete

//ckeditor

import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";
Vue.use(CKEditor);


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue ap
 *
 *
 * plication instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

// dash board

Vue.component(
    "dashboard-site-latest-employee-attendance-list",
    require("./components/dashboard/site/LatestEmployeeAttendanceComponent.vue")
);
Vue.component(
    "dashboard-site-latest-student-attendance-list",
    require("./components/dashboard/site/latestStudentAttendanceListComponent.vue")
);

Vue.component(
    "dashboard-site-employee-attendance-graph",
    require("./components/dashboard/site/dashboardEmployeeAttendanceGraphComponent.vue")
);
/* ====Global filter START =========================*/

Vue.filter("activeInactive", function(value) {
    if (value == 1) {
        return "Active";
    } else {
        return "Inactive";
    }
});
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    i18n,
    components: {},

    methods: {},
    mounted() {
        console.log("d" + document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2));
    }
});
```

and here 100+ component registration.
Is there any way to make a diffrent file and bungle it?

I mean something like this:

```
  mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js/vue")
.js("resources/js/administrator.js", "public/js/vue")
.js("resources/js/reseller.js", "public/js/vue")
.js("resources/js/user.js", "public/js/vue")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
```

Is it possible to have a main app.js file where common library import and filter and `new Vue{()}`  and component reg. in different files? I will add those bundled js based role will use the page and component.
Then the user will not be forced to download all js which is not needed for him. Now the user must download a full js file (6 Mb on prod).

Answer (score -1):

You can use laravel blade condition and stacks like

```
@push('jsscripts')
  @if($role === 'admin')
  <script src='/js/admin.js>
  @endif
@endpush
```

Comment: My problem is not related to blade. When i spit app.js file to multiple, it gives error! component not found

Comment: well you can create a js file for each and import only the components needed.